# Changed static IP on a DC by mistake and can't log in to change it back

Tags: windows-server-2003, ip, active-directory, login, domain-controller

I made a goof. I was in RDP and checking out the network settings on one of my domain controllers (Windows Server 2003 SP2) and I accidentally changed the static IP to a different subnet, and poof lost my RDP. There are no accounts set up on it that can log in locally, so I cannot log in to fix the issue. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Comment: I apologize it seems the issue wasn't related to changing the IP address, well it was partly. That domain controller became it's own primary after the IP was changed and it seems there were replication problems and it didn't have the new Administrator password I had setup on the primary DC before the mistake. Thanks anyway. Sorry don't have enough rep to answer it myself yet.

Comment: There is no such thing as a backup domain controller, unless you are in a Windows NT4 environment.

Comment: If you're still calling an Active Directory DC a PDC or BDC you most certainly should not be touching anything on the server including the IP address information.

Comment: My head hurts reading the comment added. They're *all* primary. Grrr....

Comment: @NCX001, alerting moderators about Chris S's comment isn't going to work - you may think it rude but he's right and this site is for PRO sysadmins, we expect people to keep up.

Comment: Wow, Chopper.. You're a very respectable person around here considering how much you contribute. But considering you're a moderator, that sure was a terrible way to handle the situation. Remember, "PRO sysadmin" is not the same thing as "Windows Server Expert". I'm a "pro sysadmin" yet I had no idea that they shouldn't be called backup DCs, admittedly because AD is new to me within the last year. The fact that Chris said he shouldnt even be touching IP address information is insulting and uncalled for and you, as a moderator, handled that poorly. Of course, I called it a BDC, so what do I know

Comment: Ryan - if you've had a year of experience with AD ( a product that's been around for over 10 years), and weren't aware that there's no such thing as a BDC anymore ... I just don't know what to say.

Comment: @Ryan, I wouldn't admit that if I were you. And if you don't have a basic understanding of AD, then you won't have any idea about the potential consequences of changing the IP address of one. Those can be crippling consequences.

Comment: I think that any further discussion on this topic should probably go to meta (or off-site altogether), as it's serving no useful purpose here.

Answer (score 6):

If you have physical access to the network, you can configure an IP address on a laptop with an IP in the same subnet you accidentally assigned. Try logging in from there.

Comment: This might even work remotely, with the ability to assign multiple IP addresses to one NIC.